# I've got lots of buttons (choices) in my modal, and all are needed. How do I reorganize it better?

Tags: modal-windows, options, choices, many-options

I'm making an interface that is part of a garment return merchandise system (customer didn't like the product and sends it back). Part of this interface allows customers to choose one or more reasons for their dissatisfaction with a garment.

I've got lots of structured options, and all of them are important to the product managers - they want to know what went wrong. Here's a mockup:

[image: pardon my french]

Lots of options, and quite hard to understand at a glance! I could visually separate the buttons by putting backgrounds/borders/grouping, and change some icons, but I think that it's still a lot of cognitive work.

Is there any way I can make this a little easier on the customers who fill out this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don’t see any buttons at all, which is a good thing, you only need one or two buttons for this. Of course, if you have buttons and they don’t even look like buttons, then you have real problems. But I assume you don’t mean buttons and it’s just a translation issue

Anyways, if you’re building a form to gather user’s opinions, just keep it simple. Get rid of all those icons, make simple questions and offer choices using `checkboxes` for the first group of options and `radio` input fields for the boolean choices in second group. No need to get creative. As a matter of fact.... avoid being creative, you’re already finding issues and you know the interface. Imagine what it would be for users that never seen this interface before!

Finally, offer users a free form where they can add comments if they want. It will show you care for their opinion besides your choices, and you may find valuable insights that may help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would move to a full sliders interface. The first part with 2 positions and the lower part with 3 states with a default position neutral.

It will be easier for users to play with the interface and try différents configurations.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now the user gets a lot of options and visual information.

Idea: try to cluster some of the problems in categories and let the user go through the process stepwise.
For example:

- The quality was bad
- It did not fit right
- I did not like the style

After that, the user could specify it further, e.g. *it was too big*. This way the user won't be overwhelmed by the number of choices he/she gets.